# How to add shadow at tableviewcell swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to add shadow at tableviewcell with 4 section (1 tableView with 4 tableViewCell), where the last cell I want to added shadow at 3 sides(left,right,bottom) but in another cell except last cell I just want to added shadow at 2 side(left,right). I write this code in singleton and with extension UIView.
this for last cell:

```
 func dropShadowAtBottom() {

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    self.layer.opacity = 0.3
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    self.clipsToBounds = false

}
```

and this for another cell except last cell:

```
func dropShadowAtLeftAndRight() {

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    let shadowRect: CGRect = self.layer.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4);  // inset top/bottom
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowRect).cgPath

    self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true

}
```

I call this code in cellForRow:

```
if(indexPath.row == currentOrderHistory.listOrderItems.count - 1){
            cell.bodyView.dropShadowAtBottomOnly()

        }else{
            cell.bodyView.dropShadowAtLeftAndRight()
        }
        return cell
```

now this code is work but still not perfect. there is white space between cell.

[image: picture]

I just want to make them connected.

Comment: It would really help if you post images of what you want to achieve

Comment: try to share what you want to  achieved

Comment: I already added the picture. please klik the "picture"  text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the separator from IB?

[image]

Set the **Separator** to **None**

or another way, set the separator color to translucent

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you face the problem in `dropShadowAtLeftAndRight()` in this Line

```
let shadowRect: CGRect = self.layer.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 4);
```

it will return `rect` looks like this `(0.0, 4.0, 375.0, 36.0)` in my case. on top 4px is white space and bottom also 4px white space

So your left and right shadow will start from 4 and height is 36.

to solve this issue you need to set like this

```
let shadowRect: CGRect = self.layer.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0);
```

Comment: yeah but if i change dy to 0, all cell will have bottom shadow

Comment: then you can use only "dropShadowAtBottom" method only and add two  view in your cell left and right to give left and right sheddow.